# Joomla setRedirect doesn't work

Tags: redirect, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have a simple Joomla controller, but I can't redirect anything.

According to the documentation:

```
class MyController extends MyBaseController {

 function import() {
    $link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_foo&ctrl=bar');
    $this->setRedirect($link);
  }

}
//The url contains &amp; html escaped character instead of "&"
```

This should work, but I get a malformed URL. Is there something I'm missing here? Why is Joomla converting all the "&" characters into `&amp;`'s? How am I suppose to use setRedirect?

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Alright, I fixed it. So if anyone needs it:

instead of

```
$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_foo&ctrl=bar');
$this->setRedirect($link);
```

use

```
$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_foo&ctrl=bar',false);
$this->setRedirect($link);
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you found your answer, and by the way, the boolean parameter in    `JRoute::_()` is by default true, and useful for xml compliance. What it does is that inside the static method, it uses the htmlspecialchars php function like this:     `$url = htmlspecialchars($url)` to replace the & for xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$mainframe = &JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->redirect(JURI::root()."index.php?option=com_foo&ctrl=bar","your custom message[optional]","message type[optional- warning,error,information etc]");
```

Comment: i agree with your answer @jobin cause $this->setRedirect($link); setRedirect() not defined in your custom class so use jobin answer it's really works

Comment: actually I do have it, its just I put a controller between JController and my own so my own controllers can share certain functions. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the Joomla source you can quickly see why this is happening:

```
if (headers_sent())
    {
        echo "<script>document.location.href='" . htmlspecialchars($url) . "';</script>\n";
    }
    else
    {
    ... ... ...
```

The problem is that your page has probably already output some data (via echo or some other means).
In this situation, Joomla is programmed to use a simple javascript redirect. However, in this javascript redirect it has htmlspecialchars() applied to the URL.

A simple solution is to just not use Joomlas function and directly write the javascript in a way that makes more sense:

```
echo "<script>document.location.href='" . $url . "';</script>\n";
```

This works for me :)

Answer (score -3):

/libraries/joomla/application/application.php

Find line 400

```
    // If the headers have been sent, then we cannot send an additional location header
    // so we will output a javascript redirect statement.
    if (headers_sent())
    {
        echo "<script>document.location.href='" . htmlspecialchars($url) . "';</script>\n";
    }
```

replace to

```
    // If the headers have been sent, then we cannot send an additional location header
    // so we will output a javascript redirect statement.
    if (headers_sent())
    {
        echo "<script>document.location.href='" . $url . "';</script>\n";
    }
```

This works!

Comment: This is the worst possible solution. Never modify a 3rd party library to fix something that **is not a bug**. Unless you feel comfortable issuing a pull request for the core Joomla people to merge your changes, you should not make the changes. As it is, you're probably breaking the *rest* of your application horribly, and fundamentally altering behaviors of Joomla that other 3rd party libraries may depend on.